# in web javascript, possible to get md5 of javascript file?

Tags: javascript, md5

in a web app, it is possible for `javascript` to get the `md5` of an `<script src=...>`

in my app the script files are "fingerprinted" (as per google recommendation) so they can be cached indefinitely.  for example, in the file name

```
mBShjJZcO2LeNil6CjrGA-modal.min.js`
```

the "fingerprint" is (in node.js)

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update(out.code).digest("base64").replace(/\W/g,'')
```

where `out.code` is the output of `uglifyjs`

with this I have the built-in ability to checksum the `script` files.  which seems would be very cool.

is there actually any way to do this with javascript's web security model?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Blender - do not know that I _need_ it, for sure.  but the capability is free, so thought would look into it.  have a lot of stuff coming from server, not necessarily using ssl

Comment: Did you mean a md5 genarator?

Comment: @silentboy - no - md5() and base64() are easy to get.  rather after ability to do `md5` on contents of `file.js` uploaded via `<script src='file.js'>`